# RegEx Regular pattern Matching is not working for respective Text File

Tags: java, regex

For specific word, I have to fetch full sentence/ sentences(till full stop). In that excluding Decimal point(3.75).

**Example**:

**Specific word**: "Abatacept"

**Paragraph**:

```
  Review of Systems:
General:  Complains of chills, sweats, and malaise; denies fever, anorexia, fatigue, weakness, weight loss, and sleep                                          
disorder.
CV: Denies difficulty breathing at night, near fainting, chest pain or discomfort, racing/skipping heart beats, fatigue, 
lightheadedness, shortness of breath with exertion, palpitations, swelling of hands or feet, difficulty breathing while lying 
down, fainting, leg cramps with exertion, bluish discoloration of lips or nails, and weight gain 3.785 **Abatacept**.
Resp: Complains of cough; denies sleep disturbances due to breathing, shortness of breath, coughing up blood, chest 
discomfort, wheezing, excessive sputum, and excessive snoring.
```

From Paragraph, I want sentence/sentences in which match Abatacept word.
Here that sentence is:

```
CV: Denies difficulty breathing at night, near fainting, chest pain or discomfort, racing/skipping heart beats, fatigue, 
    lightheadedness, shortness of breath with exertion, palpitations, swelling of hands or feet, difficulty breathing while lying 
    down, fainting, leg cramps with exertion, bluish discoloration of lips or nails, and weight gain 3.785 **Abatacept**.
```

Code:

```
word_re = "((\\.(\\s|\\r).*)|(((?!\\.\\s).)*))(\\b(Abatacept)\\b.*?)((\\.\\s)|(\\.\\D)|(\\.$))";
Pattern re = Pattern.compile(word_re ,Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.COMMENTS |  Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                Matcher match = re.matcher(textString);
                String sentenceString="";
                while (match .find()) {
                    sentenceString = match.group(1);
                    System.out.println(sentenceString);
                }
```

Could You please suggest me. So I can fetch perfect sentence/ sentences from the textFile in which that specific word is there.
Thank You.

Comment: The context is completely unclear. Be more precise.

Comment: Asking for debugging help is off-topic for this site. Please use a debugger.

Comment: Thanks fge and Vince. But I utilized full two days to made this expression. But not all combination is taking this regex.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about java but you can use this regex:

```
(.*\bAbatacept\b.*[\b(.\s)])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gK8uC7/5)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But when you enter before the word "Abatacept" in your Demo then its not working. https://regex101.com/r/gK8uC7/4 
If you can see your regex not taking space.

Comment: Sorry din't get you about the  before the word.  do you want to catch this`**Abatacept**` or not ?

Comment: Please  check this link: https://regex101.com/r/gK8uC7/4
here, only word "Abatacept" is fetching from the sentence. I want full sentence.

Comment: @Neel But here "Abatacept" is in the next line. You want to consider sentences which span through multiple lines even after a `\n` ?

Comment: yes. Example: "My name is Neel. I have 
Abatacept. I dont know Regex. But I 
like Abatacept."

Answer: "I have Abatacept. But I like Abatacept."

In general I can  say that "Fetch the sentence start from Last Sentence Full stop to Current line Full stop."